# UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight - alternative to show card after card?

Tags: ios, scroll, playing-cards

Whats the best method to display a single playing card on screen whereupon...

When the user swipes it, the existing card scrolls off, whilst at the same time the new card scrolls on ?

Is UIScrollView the best option, where I could perhaps place all playing cards into a single spitesheet?

Right now my playing cards consists of 52 separate pngs plus rear.png

Answer (score 1):

Check out [iCarousel](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel) !! It supports numerous different types of scroll modes and works very smoothly,too.

Comment: I'll load it into XCode tonight and give it a whirl.